# When and how should I update my collision grid?

Tags: c++, collision-detection

When and how should I update my collision grid?

Current implementation:

1. set entity velocities
2. buildGrid(): add all entities with collision to the grid
3. handleCollision(timePerFrame, entities): handle all collisions, adjust velocities accordinly
4. grid.clear(): clear grid
5. move entities

If I have for example 4000 stationary entities and only 20 moving entities, I remove and add 4000 entities to the grid every update for no reason.

What would be the good way to update only cells that require updating?

Only idea that I have currently is that after collision check I remove moving entities from the grid and during buildGrid() I add only moving entities to the grid.

All help is welcome.

Grid implementation

```
// CollisionGrid Cell
class Cell
{
    public:
        typedef std::set<Entity*> Container;

    public:
        void        setNeighbours(Cell* left, Cell* right, Cell* up, Cell* down);
        void        addEntity(Entity* entity);
        Container   getNearbyEntities() const;
        void        clear();

    private:
        void        appendEntitiesTo(Container& entities) const;

    private:
        Container   mEntities;

    protected:
        Cell*       mLeft;
        Cell*       mRight;
        Cell*       mUp;
        Cell*       mDown;
};


// CollisionGrid
class CollisionGrid
{
    public:
                            CollisionGrid(float sceneWidth, float sceneHeight, float cellSize);

        void                clear();
        void                addEntity(Entity* entity);
        Cell::Container     getNearbyEntities(Entity* entity);

    private:
        int                 getIdForPosition(const sf::Vector2f position);

    public:
        int                 mCols;
        int                 mRows;
        std::vector<Cell>   mCells;

    private:
        float               mSceneWidth;
        float               mSceneHeight;
        float               mCellSize;
};


// CollisionGrid Cell
void Cell::setNeighbours(Cell* left, Cell* right, Cell* up, Cell* down)
{
    mLeft = left;
    mRight = right;
    mUp = up;
    mDown = down;
}


void Cell::addEntity(Entity* entity)
{
    mEntities.insert(entity);
}


Cell::Container Cell::getNearbyEntities() const
{
    Container entities = mEntities;

    if (mLeft != nullptr)
        mLeft->appendEntitiesTo(entities);
    if (mRight != nullptr)
        mRight->appendEntitiesTo(entities);
    if (mUp != nullptr)
        mUp->appendEntitiesTo(entities);
    if (mDown != nullptr)
        mDown->appendEntitiesTo(entities);

    return entities;
}


void Cell::clear()
{
    mEntities.clear();
}


void Cell::appendEntitiesTo(Container& entities) const
{
    entities.insert(mEntities.begin(), mEntities.end());
}


// CollisionGrid
CollisionGrid::CollisionGrid(float sceneWidth, float sceneHeight, float cellSize)
: mSceneWidth(sceneWidth)
, mSceneHeight(sceneHeight)
, mCellSize(cellSize)
, mCols((int)floor(sceneWidth / cellSize))
, mRows((int)floor(sceneHeight / cellSize))
{
    mCells = std::vector<Cell>(mCols*mRows);

    for (int id = 0; id < mCols*mRows; ++id)
    {
        Cell* left = nullptr;
        Cell* right = nullptr;
        Cell* up = nullptr;
        Cell* down = nullptr;

        if (id % mCols > 0)
            left = &mCells[id - 1];
        if (id % mCols < mCols - 1)
            right = &mCells[id + 1];
        if (id > mCols - 1)
            up = &mCells[id - mCols];
        if (id < mCols * (mRows - 1))
            down = &mCells[id + mCols];

        mCells[id].setNeighbours(left, right, up, down);
    }
}


void CollisionGrid::clear()
{
    for (Cell& cell : mCells)
        cell.clear();
}


void CollisionGrid::addEntity(Entity* entity)
{
    mCells[getIdForPosition(entity->position)].addEntity(entity);
}


Cell::Container CollisionGrid::getNearbyEntities(Entity* entity)
{
    return mCells[getIdForPosition(entity->position)].getNearbyEntities();
}


int CollisionGrid::getIdForPosition(const sf::Vector2f position)
{
    return int(floor(position.x / mCellSize) + floor(position.y / mCellSize) * mCols);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to implement Update function to your hierarchy.
You can add an Update function directly to your CollisionGrid, Cell and Entities.

```
    void CollisionGrid::Update()
    {
            for(vector<Cell>::iterator it = mCells.begin(); it != mCells.end(); ++it)
            {
                    it->Update();
            }
    }

    void Cell::Update()
    {
            for(set<Entity>::iterator it = mEntities.begin(); it != mEntities.end(); ++it)
            {
                    it->Update();
            }
    }

    void Entity::Update()
    {
            // Update with the entity behaviour
            // For example : Move Entity
            // You can create a class that inherite from Entity that will be a movable class
    }
```

The idea behind this is, when we update the state of the environnement, we update every sub component of the environnement and sub component of these component and so forth. Each component Update according with their specific behaviour. For example, you might need to add a reference to the Cell in the Entity so you can also Update on which cell the Entity is moving when updating the Entity for example.

You can also read about Entity and Component programming which is a common programming method in video game for example.

Comment: Clearing and rebuilding grid each update was the easiest way to update all entity locations on the grid (also quite inefficient).
I added 2 more steps to make current use case a bit clearer.

Comment: Why can't you keep the grid for each update and only update entities that moved (with a velocity that != 0). Rebuilding the grid is not the best method to update entities' position.

Comment: That is what I'm asking: how should I handle updating so only those entities position that moved around are updated in grid.